# SSRS FetchXML number of days between 2 dates excluding weekends

Tags: reporting-services, crm, dynamics-crm-365, fetchxml

I have 2 fields of DateTime from CRM 365 Online and want to create a custom report with a textbox that calculates the number of days between 2 dates excluding weekends in FetchXML (Bonus to also exclude holidays from the standard holiday schedule)

Any ideas?

Comment: In FetchXML this is not possible.

Comment: Thanks, i ended up creating a scheduled Flow once a day that calculates the mentioned days and pulled the field for my report